# Programmatic MotionEvents are highlighting content in my webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm using pretty standard code I found on here to programmatically trigger a click, (say for instance I want to click on a link) on my android WebView but it only highlights content at the specified x,y coordinates.

```
long when = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
float pressure = 1.0f;
int action = 0;
int source = MotionEvent.ACTION_UP;
MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(when, when + 50, action, x, y, pressure, 1.0f, 0, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0);
event.setSource(source);
mWebView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
```

I'm very new at Android programming so I may be missing something obvious, any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  How do you know hilighting isn't appropriate?  Also, I only see an up here, no downs.   Sending an up without a corresponding down first could break a variety of things.

Comment: I just want to click on, say, a link in my webview and not just highlight the link. I've sent downs as well and it still won't click properly

Comment: Well I see you're setting the source of the event as ACTION_UP.  That isn't the source-  its an action.  The source is the type of device, like InputDevice.SOURCE_CLASS_POINTER

Comment: indeed it looks like that was a problem! thank you, if you want to answer with that I can choose it.